# Solve differential equation $y=(y')^2\cdot e^{y'}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve differential equation $y=(y')^2\cdot e^{y'}$.

First I substitute $\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}=p$  and    get $y=(p)^2\cdot e^{p}$.

Differentiate both sides by $x$.
$p=(2p+p^2)\cdot e^p\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d} p}{\mathrm{d} x}$

$dx=(p+2)\cdot e^p\cdot dp$

$x=e^p \cdot (p+1)$

What to do with that?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You have got to $$x=e^{y’}(y’+1) $$ Now notice from the original DE, we have $e^{y’}=\frac{y}{(y’)^2} $. Substitute it in to get $$x(y’)^2=yy’+y $$

$$x(y’)^2-yy’-y=0  \\ y’=\frac{y\pm \sqrt{y^2+4xy}}{2x} \\ 2y’=\frac yx \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac yx\right)^2 +4\frac yx}$$ Now substitute in $y=tx$.

Comment: frankly speaking, no!

Comment: @Hrackadont How about now?